# how to see all query content of mysql 5.7 of sys.statement_analysis

Tags: mysql

I am using this query in Sequel Pro to check the query sql of sys.statement_analysis table, but some content could not show completely:

```
select query
from sys.statement_analysis 
order by exec_count 
desc limit 40;
```

how to see full content of query(longtext data type)?

[image]

Comment: What's your ide?

Comment: Sequel Pro @P.Salmon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but I just found the answer.

The "statement_analysis" is a view, so you can use "`show create view sys.statement_analysis`" to get the "create view" query.

The "create view" starts with the "sys.format_statement" command. Remove it from the query, and you get a query like this:

```
    SELECT 
    `sys`.`format_statement`(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`DIGEST_TEXT`) AS `query`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SCHEMA_NAME` AS `db`,
    IF(((`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED` > 0)
            OR (`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_NO_INDEX_USED` > 0)),
        '*',
        '') AS `full_scan`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`COUNT_STAR` AS `exec_count`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ERRORS` AS `err_count`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_WARNINGS` AS `warn_count`,
    FORMAT_PICO_TIME(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_TIMER_WAIT`) AS `total_latency`,
    FORMAT_PICO_TIME(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`MAX_TIMER_WAIT`) AS `max_latency`,
    FORMAT_PICO_TIME(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`AVG_TIMER_WAIT`) AS `avg_latency`,
    FORMAT_PICO_TIME(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_LOCK_TIME`) AS `lock_latency`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ROWS_SENT` AS `rows_sent`,
    ROUND(IFNULL((`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ROWS_SENT` / NULLIF(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`COUNT_STAR`,
                            0)),
                    0),
            0) AS `rows_sent_avg`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ROWS_EXAMINED` AS `rows_examined`,
    ROUND(IFNULL((`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ROWS_EXAMINED` / NULLIF(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`COUNT_STAR`,
                            0)),
                    0),
            0) AS `rows_examined_avg`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ROWS_AFFECTED` AS `rows_affected`,
    ROUND(IFNULL((`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_ROWS_AFFECTED` / NULLIF(`performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`COUNT_STAR`,
                            0)),
                    0),
            0) AS `rows_affected_avg`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_CREATED_TMP_TABLES` AS `tmp_tables`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES` AS `tmp_disk_tables`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_SORT_ROWS` AS `rows_sorted`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_SORT_MERGE_PASSES` AS `sort_merge_passes`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`DIGEST` AS `digest`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`FIRST_SEEN` AS `first_seen`,
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`LAST_SEEN` AS `last_seen`
FROM
    `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`
ORDER BY `performance_schema`.`events_statements_summary_by_digest`.`SUM_TIMER_WAIT` DESC;
```

Now you can run this query and get the full sql statement.

Comment: Another less "hacky" way to do it is using the query `select * from performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest where digest = <DIGEST>`. Just use the hash from the column "digest" from the query that you want to analyze.